# Create a square function estimator with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm still very new to neural networks. I try to achieve the following with Keras:

I have a set of data where **f(x) = x^2 + 3**. Like this:

```
x       f(x)
 -10    103
-9.9    101.01
-9.8    99.04
-9.7    97.09
...
9.7     97.09
9.8     99.04
9.9    101.01
10     103
```

So I try to build a model that can predict values f(x) based on x. I think that must be a simple thing but I couldn't find any hint. I get only outputs ranging from 0 to 1 (I guess due to normalization?) and they also seem to be crap.

```
# Import the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv("simple_network/Linear Data.csv", header=None).values
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(dataset[:,0:1], dataset[:,1], 
                                                    test_size=0.25,)
# Now we build the model
neural_network = Sequential() # create model
neural_network.add(Dense(5, input_dim=1, activation='sigmoid')) # hidden layer
neural_network.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) # output layer
neural_network.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
neural_network_fitted = neural_network.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1000, verbose=0, 
                                           batch_size=X_train.shape[0], initial_epoch=0)
```

I suspect I need to somehow cater for the fact that expect an interval value as an output, not a nominal or ordinal value. Any idea?

Comment: Try to change `sigmoid` activation to `linear` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you use `sigmoid` as the activation function for your output layer. If you look at the formula of the sigmoid function (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)), you can see that its output values lies in the range from `0.0` to `1.0`. So, try to replace the activation function of the last layer to `linear`. This way, the non-linearity will be handled by your hidden layer (with a non-linear activation function), and the output layer will be used for scaling and adding bias if needed.

Comment: Thank you FalconUA and Marcin, it solved my problem. Of course the output should be linear, now I understand the dependency.